# O poder do javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, java-ee

Recentemente vi um [Infográfico](http://www.iinterativa.com.br/infografico-20-linguagens-de-programacao-mais-populares/) apontando `JavaScript` como a linguagem mais usada no ano de 2015. E também direto vejo aqui no SOpt vários posts sobre `JQuery` e `JavaScript`. Minha pergunta é a seguinte, é mais vantajoso utilizar apenas `JavaScript`, `Html` e `Css` para desenvolver sites e sistemas web? Ou utilizar o JavaScript em projetos JavaEE? Levando em conta fatores como dificuldade e produtividade.

Comment: Não sei se vai chegar a ser fechada por ser baseada em opiniões, mas `Javascript` é client side, enquanto `Java` é server side, então é conforme sua necessidade e um não elimina o outro.

Comment: Entendi, não conheço muito bem de JavaScript e quase não uso em sistemas web que faço em java. Esse é um dos motivos dessa dúvida também.

Comment: De uma pesquisada sobre nodeJs e angularJs

Comment: Beleza, vou pesquisar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente JavaScript vem ganhando muito espaço nos últimos anos, principalmente devido às alterações no cenário do desenvolvimento web. Com o advento e popularidade de bibliotecas como AngularJS, foi possível reduzir ainda mais a dependência de uma linguagem server-side (como Java, C#, PHP, etc.) em projetos web.

Pra completar, a ascensão do Node.js permitiu o desenvolvimento de aplicações web completas utilizando apenas JavaScript como linguagem de programação (claro, HTML e CSS na parte de layout).

Então, é possível sim usar apenas JavaScript, porém essa escolha vai depender muito da situação e do programador. Eu, por exemplo, trabalho com C# e PHP muito bem e não vejo a necessidade de usar Node.js no back-end de minhas aplicações, mas é bom saber que isso é possível e se em algum momento isso for requisito ou vantagem para um projeto, usarei sem problemas. Por exemplo, o Microsft Azure suporta o desenvolvimento de serviços na nuvem com Node.js, mas também (óbvio) suporta C#, então por enquanto vou ficando com C#.

O JavaScript, porém, sempre estará presente no front-end das aplicações, atuando na parte de validações, Ajax, animações, etc.

Espero ter ajudado. Um abraço.

Comment: Muito obrigado, já comecei a estudar Node.js e vou ver como é. Eu gosto muito de Java porém estou querendo expandir meu conhecimento e não ficar preso a apenas uma linguagem.

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, o que seria o Azure? é um servidor pra mim colocar minha aplicação online? Ou é um serviço que me permite programar em nuvem?

Comment: O Azure é a plataforma de computação em nuvem da Microsoft. Nela você pode sim hospedar web sites das mais variadas tecnologias, porém o serviço não ser resume a isso. No Azure você conta, por exemplo, com máquinas virtuais, bancos de dados, serviços de notificação mobile, entre muitas outras ferramentas que lhe permitem utilizar os conceitos "As A Service" como PaaS, SaaS e IaaS. Aconselho fortemente dar uma pesquisada a respeito, pois é uma plataforma excelente.

Comment: Beleza, vou terminar de estudar Node.js e ja tento fazer algo no Azure